# Is Void really uninstantiable?

Tags: java, reflection, void

The [javadoc for `Void`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) says:

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

but the constructor is simply:

```
private Void() {}
```

and this code instantiates a `Void`:

```
Constructor<Void> c = Void.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
c.setAccessible(true);
Void v = c.newInstance(); // Hello sailor
```

So `Void` is *not* uninstantiable.

Would there have been a way to make `Void` truly uninstantiable?

Comment: Out of curiosity: do you need it? ;) I guess it is only a placeholder for the reflection API for methods _returning_ `void`... Maybe of help only for proxies?

Comment: If you use reflections, you could do lot of things which are not possible by using API.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Making your constructor private, and not having any other constructor that can be accessed by outside, makes a class *un-instantiable*.

However, you cannot avoid it from being accessed using `Reflection API`. Using reflection, you can do, what is not allowed normally.

But, if you really want your class to be *uninstantiable*, even through *Reflection*, you can `throw` an *Unchecked Exception* from the *constructor*.

```
private MyClass() {
    throw UnsupportedOperationException("Can't instantiate class");
}
```

In which case, when you create the instance using `Constructor#newInstance()` method, it will throw an [`InvocationTargetException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html), as quoted in comments by @Alex.

Here's the documentation of [`Constructor#newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) method, which declares a list of exception to be thrown, one of them is [`InvocationTargetException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html), and it says that: -

> throws:  
> InvocationTargetException - if the underlying constructor
>   throws an exception.

Comment: I don't think the exception would need to be unchecked.  It would also work if it threw a checked one (perhaps `java.lang.IllegalAccessException`?).

Comment: @matts I think an unchecked exception would be preferred here. For one, it makes for less code (no `throws` clause), which is always a good thing.

Comment: @matts.. If you used `CheckedException`, and handled it in calling code, then moving further in that code may cause some problem because you might be using the instance you tried to create. In this case, if we don't want the class to be instantiated, it would be better to halt the execution with appropriate message, rather than handling it.

Comment: I don't think the choice of checked vs. unchecked really matters, in any case it will be wrapped in InvocationTargetException if the constructor is invoked via reflection.

Comment: Can't understand why so much of downvotes here, and that too without a single comment.

Comment: sun.misc.Unsafe allows an instance to be created without calling the constructor. Edit: didn't read the answer below this before I commented.

Comment: You'd need to make the class final also, in order to prevent subclasses to be written - because once you have an instance of a subclass, you have an instance of a parent class.

Comment: @Phil (I know, years later, but...) Unless the subclass is nested inside the parent class the _`private`_ constructor is not visible, leading to a compilation error. Even when nested, if an exception is thrown by the parent's constructor then the subclass will also throw an exception upon instantiation; the exception can't even be caught (in the subclass constructor) because you can't surround a call to `super()` in a try-catch block. That said, making the class `final` better communicates intent and there's no reason for an un-instantiable class to be extensible.

Answer (score 31):

Rohit is quite right that throwing an exception is "good enough" for most use cases.  However, it looks like it might be possible to [bypass even that, using sun.misc.Unsafe](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html#allocateInstance%28Class%29):

> public native Object allocateInstance(Class cls) throws
> InstantiationException
>
> Allocate an instance but do not run any
> constructor. Initializes the class if it has not yet been.

(Note that I haven't actually tested that this works)

Answer (score 11):

The Reflection API breaks all kinds of "rules" like this, just like being able to modify `final` fields.  There are many complaints about the fact that it allows you to break the hard and fast rules of Java, but that's how it is.

Without Reflection (or @StevenSchlansker's crazy `Unsafe` API posted below), it's not possible to instantiate.  As long as Reflection is allowed, though, these workarounds will exist.

In [Oracle's own Reflection tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), they list the benefits and drawbacks.  It's up to you to decide which is greater.

Also, see this question: [What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)