# Different kind of singleton pattern

Tags: java, java-8

I'm studying basic software design pattern.

The basic implementation of singleton classes are written like this:

```
    public class MyObject{

       private volatile static MyObject obj;

       private MyObject(){/*Do some heavy stuff here*/}

       public static synchronized MyObject getInstance(){
         if(obj==null)
            obj=new MyObject();
         return obj;
       }    
    }
```

But as I have undestood calling synchronized methods can be heavy.

I while back I red a book the introduced this kind of implementation of Singleton class:

```
public class MyObjectHolder {

private volatile static Supplier<MyObject> myObjectSupplier = () -> createMyObj();
//myObjectSupplier is changed on the first 'get()' call

public static MyObject getMyObject(){
    return myObjectSupplier.get();
}

private static synchronized MyObject createMyObj(){
    class MyObjectFactory implements Supplier<MyObject> {
        private final MyObject clockTimer = new MyObject();
        public MyObject get() { return clockTimer; }
    }


    if(!MyObjectFactory.class.isInstance(myObjectSupplier)) {
        myObjectSupplier = new MyObjectFactory();
    }
    return myObjectSupplier.get();
}

public static class MyObject{

    private MyObject(){
        /*Do some heavy stuff here*/
    }

    public void someMethod(){
        /* ... */
    }
}

}


...   


    {
        /*In main MyObject instantiation*/
        MyObjectHolder.MyObject obj = MyObjectHolder.getMyObject();

    }
```

Now after the first call for 'createMyObj()' has been has been finished, there is no heavy burden of synchronized method calling and the is no if check neither.

Do you think there is something wrong with this kind of implementation?

ps. MyObject does not have to be an inner class of MyObjectHold but I thought it looked nice.

Comment: It just looks convoluted to me. You have three classes just to ensure that there is only one instance of only one class. Plus you have both a `Factory` (that doesn't create anything, so it isn't really a factory after all) and a `Supplier` (which actually does create something). Take a look at the Initialization-on-demand holder idiom in the Wikipedia "Singleton pattern" article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: That said, it's rarely the case that a `Singleton` is a good idea. It usually ends up being a `Multiton`, i.e. one of some class for each of a set of things. It just looks like a `Singleton` because you haven't found the set of things yet.

Comment: stop being a goofball and trying to reinvent the wheel.  It is fine to learn how to implement a signleton, but it is value free to actually attempt to use your own "roll-you-own" implementation.  Also, singleton is often a terrible solution.

Comment: See also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16106598/1441122 regarding the initialization-on-demand holder idiom.

Answer (score 5):

**[UPDATED]** Another solution that is called [**Initialization on Demand Holder idiom**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) :

```
public class SingletonObject {

    private static final AtomicInteger INSTANCE_COUNT = new AtomicInteger();
    private static final AtomicInteger INVOKE_COUNT = new AtomicInteger();

    private static final class LazyHolder {

        private static final SingletonObject INSTANCE = new SingletonObject();

    }

    private SingletonObject() {
        System.out.println("new SingletonObject");
        INSTANCE_COUNT.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public static SingletonObject getInstance() {
        INVOKE_COUNT.getAndIncrement();
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public static int getInstanceCount() {
        return INSTANCE_COUNT.get();
    }

    public static int getInvokeCount() {
        return INVOKE_COUNT.get();
    }

}
```

to prove that it's thread-safe :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int n = 1000;
    List<Callable<SingletonObject>> invokers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        invokers.add(SingletonObject::getInstance);
    }
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
    es.invokeAll(invokers);
    es.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Number of Instances = " + SingletonObject.getInstanceCount());
    System.out.println("Number of Invokes = " + SingletonObject.getInvokeCount());
}
```

Output :

```
new SingletonObject
Number of Instances = 1
Number of Invokes = 1000
```

**EDIT (after [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116162/different-kind-of-singleton-pattern#comment57976417_35118259)'s comment)** :

the use of the **Nested Holder Class** is *somewhat necessary* to **Lazily Initialize** the `SingletonObject`.

```
public class SingletonObject {

    private static final SingletonObject INSTANCE = new SingletonObject();

    private SingletonObject() {
        System.out.println("new SingletonObject");
    }

    public static SingletonObject getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void anotherStaticMethod() {
        System.out.println("I don't need the SingletonObject Instance...");
    }

}
```

So what happens if someone invokes the `anotherStaticMethod()`?

```
new SingletonObject
I don't need the SingletonObject Instance...
```

**UPDATE** :

The page at [WIKIPEDIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) says :

> The implementation of the idiom relies on the initialization phase of execution within the [Java Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine) (JVM) as specified by the Java Language Specification (JLS). When the class `SingletonObject` is loaded by the JVM, the class goes through initialization. Since the class does not have any static variables to initialize, the initialization completes trivially. The static class definition `LazyHolder` within it is not initialized until the JVM determines that `LazyHolder` must be executed. The static class `LazyHolder` is only executed when the static method `getInstance` is invoked on the class `SingletonObject`, and the first time this happens the JVM will load and initialize the `LazyHolder` class. The initialization of the `LazyHolder` class results in static variable `INSTANCE` being initialized by executing the (private) constructor for the outer class `SingletonObject`. Since the class initialization phase is guaranteed by the JLS to be serial, i.e., non-concurrent, no further synchronization is required in the static `getInstance` method during loading and initialization. And since the initialization phase writes the static variable `INSTANCE` in a serial operation, all subsequent concurrent invocations of the `getInstance` will return the same correctly initialized `INSTANCE` without incurring any additional synchronization overhead.
>   This gives a **highly efficient thread-safe** "singleton" cache, without synchronization overhead; benchmarking indicates it to be far faster than even uncontended synchronization. However, the idiom is singleton-specific and not extensible to pluralities of objects (e.g. a map-based cache).

Also keep an eye on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom#Only_One_Chance_To_Initialize).

Comment: Yeah. This was also pointed out by 'Bohemian'  (link by Stuart Marks) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106260/thread-safe-singleton-class/16106598#16106598
To me this seems to be the neatest (and most efficient?) way to ensure that only instance will be created.

Comment: There is no need for the nested holder class. The `static final` variable can be declared right inside the `SingletonObject` class. It will still be lazily initialized and thread safe.

Comment: @Holger Yep, that's right as long as there are no other `static` methods in the `class`.

Comment: @FaNaJ: that’s only relevant, if these other `static` methods do not need to access the singleton instance anyway. And if you have such methods, they are obviously misplaced…

Comment: @Holger By using the **nested holder class** we are sure that `SingletonObject` will be instantiated if and only if we call the `getInstance` method.

Comment: thank you for proving my point. This `anotherStaticMethod()` does not fulfill any useful purpose and, as already said, if it did without using the singleton instance, it is *misplaced*. Why should a method not having anything to do with the singleton be placed inside the singleton class? But even if you place such method inside the class, in real life, it’s rather rare to have applications using this special kind of `static` methods of a singleton class without ever using the ordinary methods. That nested class is wasting resources to optimize a very unlikely corner case.

Comment: @Holger my pleasure... I agree with you. so I think which one to choose depends on the developers to fit their needs based on the situation.

Comment: I think the term "lazily initialized" needs to be nailed down. The reason for the nested holder class is to allow the instance of the Singleton to be created as a result of the first invocation of `getInstance()`. That is what "lazily initialized" usually means in this context. If `INSTANCE` is a member of `SingletonObject` it will be instantiated when the `SingletonObject` class is loaded. This is not "lazily initialized", it is rather eager.

Comment: @Erick G. Hagstrom: this is wrong. You are mixing up *loading* and *initialization* of Java classes. Java guarantees that the *initialization* will happen right before the first use, i.e. the invocation of a method of the class, regardless of when the *loading* happened. Otherwise, using an inner class was no help either, as the *loading* is allowed to be implemented eagerly by a JVM.

Comment: @Holger good distinction. There's too much to say here. I'll post another question specifically about the difference between using the holder and leaving `INSTANCE` on `SingletonObject`. It may be a day or three before I get to it.

Comment: Is there any reason to dabble with something like this in real code, instead of using singleton enum?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to implement the Singleton pattern in java is to simply make the class an enum instead:

```
public enum MyObject{

   Obj;

   MyObject(){/*Do some heavy stuff here*/}

}
```

Obj is guaranteed by the specification to only be created once on the first use of it.

Comment: That probably can be a good trick, but I'v undestood that making it enum does not make it thread safe?

Comment: @Nabuska  creation (and the constructor) of Obj is guaranteed to be thread safe. Of course other methods you define for MyObject  will not be.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. You should add "So you ask what is wrong with your approach. It doesn't use this." Then it would answer the written question ;-)

Comment: Technically, you're right. I posted my answer more to present another option to consider than a correction. I think there are merits to explicitly writing the logic yourself when learning / practicing concepts. To that end, no i don't think the OP is doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Singleton pattern breaks [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (SRP) - because the class has to do two things:

1. It's primary task
2. Enforcing singleton-ness.

Your second approach is trying to delegate this  'Enforcing singleton-ness' to a separate class - following SRP. If you are using a dependency injection framework like spring, you can achieve the same effect by only defining MyObject class and declaring this class with a 'singleton' scope in the spring context.

Comment: I don't think "enforcing singleton-ness" is a task, any more than, say, "enforcing immutability"... Especially so in Java, where you'd use singleton enum anyway, so the language does all the enforcing.