# Singleton connection object creation in java using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, singleton

I am trying to create a connection object using singleton design pattern.Is this the right way to do. Please help me with the appropriate way of doing this.

```
package com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;


public class CreateConnection {

        private static Connection connection = null;
        static final String drivername = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
        private static CreateConnection instance;

        private CreateConnection() {

            try{
                Class.forName(drivername);
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://hddev-c01-edge-01:50045/","phodisvc","B1GD4T4dev");
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

        public static CreateConnection getInstance()
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                instance = new CreateConnection();
            }

            return instance;
        }
}
```

Comment: This way of initializing the instance is **not** Thread-Safe! You need to add synchronization if you really want to use lazy initialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread Safe singleton class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106260/thread-safe-singleton-class)

Comment: But the more important question to answer is if you really want your CreateConnection-Class to be singleton. This would, for example, mean that you can never have multiple connections to databases unless each of them has their own class. It would also create a multi-threading bottleneck - you may need to synchronize all access to your Connection-Object because all threads in your app use the same instance (which is kind of the point of the singleton). And it means that the lifetime of your singleton object is that of the application - it can never be garbage collected.

Comment: Another issue with Singletons is that they make it easy to create hidden dependencies between classes. They make it hard to replace their behavior during testing. All in all they are pretty much an Anti-Pattern that is only appropriate in rare cases.

Answer (score 0):

Take my example it works. (Just replace the URL, username and password with yours)

```
public class DatabaseConnection {

public static Connection con = null;

public static void dbConnect(String drv, String url, String usr, String pwd) {

    // CHARGEMENT DU PILOTE
    try {
        Class.forName(drv);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // CONNEXION BDD
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, pwd);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}