# Infinite recursion composition class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis, infinite-recursion

I have an infinite recursion in my program where I have a field in a class, that has the same class in its field.  They are singletons, but this is not what causes them not to construct.  By the way I wrote the program I actually cannot remove the phases array.

```
abstract class Phase{
  protected String phaseName;
  protected char[] keys;
  protected String[] commands;
  protected Phase[] phases;
  protected StringBuilder pattern;

}

class RemotePhase extends Phase{
  private static RemotePhase remotePhase;

  protected RemotePhase(){
    phaseName="Remote.";
    commands=new String[]{"Lock/unlock windows", "Toggle door", "Select dog menu"};
    setPattern();

    //Just below here starts an infinite loop
    phases=new Phase[]{FixWindows.getFixWindows(), ToggleDoor.getToggleDoor(), SelectDogPhase.getSelectDogPhase()};

  }

  public static RemotePhase getRemotePhase(){
    if(remotePhase==null){
      remotePhase=new RemotePhase();
    }
    return remotePhase;
  }
}

final class FixWindows extends Phase{
  private static FixWindows windows;
  private RemotePhase remotePhase;

  private FixWindows(){

    //execution keeps coming here as FixWindows object is never constructed
    remotePhase=RemotePhase.getRemotePhase();

  }

  public static FixWindows getFixWindows(){
    if(windows==null){
      windows=new FixWindows();
    }
    return windows;
  }
}
```

I have tried making RemotePhase a static class and FixWindows use it for its members, but I ran into errors trying to override the non static methods of the abstract class, and trying to call them from FixWindows in nonstatic context.  I prefer to not make it static though, because I would have to make an additional class just to refer to RemotePhase.

Any ways to make this work though.  Thanks

Comment: It's an infinite recursion rather than an infinite loop.

Comment: Change `FixWindows` constructor and pass `RemotePhase` (this) to build that in `getFixWindows` or just set `remotePhase` in `getFixWindows`. Try to avoid calling constructor in other constructor. Your static methods are good for setting such these stuff

Comment: Can you show it please

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16106598/256196) for a simple way to implement a singleton

Comment: thank you, reminds me that I saw this strategy in an article

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you need to store a reference to a singleton while you can always access it by the static getter ? This would enable lazy access to `RemotePhase` from `FixWindows`, and fix your circular dependency. Therefore, the cleanest fix is simply to not call the getter inside the constuctor of `FixWindows`.

```
final class FixWindows extends Phase{
  private static FixWindows windows;

  private FixWindows(){
      // does nothing but preventing external classes to instantiate it
  }

  public static synchronized FixWindows getFixWindows(){
    if(windows==null){
      windows=new FixWindows();
    }
    return windows;
  }

  public void methodThatRequiresTheRemotePhase(){
    doSomeStuff(RemotePhase.getRemotePhase());
  }
}
```

By the way, I should warn you that your code is not thread-safe. Your getters should be synchronized.

Comment: @DannyP. I edited my post with an example and a warning on thread-safety

Comment: Okay, I can understand better now... While I was writing the code to set up the automatic execution of the phases, I ended up having to store an array of phases for each phase.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing but I would recommend to think twice about using this many singletons. Usually you would use singletons mainly to avoid loading or serializing very large resources multiple times (or thread pools, stuff like that), but you don't seem to be doing that so I wonder if such complexity is useful

Comment: Okay I am not using it for that, I just have a map returned by another map, that is set by looping through these arrays: names, keys, and phases.  I wanted to use only one object for the phases and other classes and keep track.

Answer (score 1):

*This is an answer to how to break an initialization loop. [Answer by @Dici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810225/5221149) is however better, since you shouldn't need to store singleton references to `RemotePhase` in the first place.*

Your problem is that the singleton-initializers are co-dependent.

One way to break that, is to assign the static singleton field of `RemotePhase` *before* the `RemotePhase` in initialization is complete. This will then ensure that when initialization progresses, and the `FixWindows` singleton object is constructed, it can find the (partially) initialized `RemotePhase` singleton object.

So, chance code like this:

```
private RemotePhase() {
    phaseName = "Remote.";
    commands = new String[] { "Lock/unlock windows",
                              "Toggle door",
                              "Select dog menu" };
    setPattern();
}

private void init() {
    phases = new Phase[] { FixWindows.getFixWindows(),
                           ToggleDoor.getToggleDoor(),
                           SelectDogPhase.getSelectDogPhase() };
}

public static RemotePhase getRemotePhase() {
    if (remotePhase == null) {
        remotePhase = new RemotePhase(); // assigns partially initialized object
        remotePhase.init();              // completes initialization
    }
    return remotePhase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid calling constructor in another ones. You can use setters instead.

I show this idea for `FixWindows`, you can use the same for other subclasses

```
abstract class Phase{
  protected String phaseName;
  protected char[] keys;
  protected String[] commands;
  protected Phase[] phases;
  protected StringBuilder pattern;

}

class RemotePhase extends Phase{
  private static RemotePhase remotePhase;

  protected RemotePhase(){
    phaseName="Remote.";
    commands=new String[]{"Lock/unlock windows", "Toggle door", "Select dog menu"};
    setPattern();

    //Just below here starts an infinite loop
    phases=new Phase[]{FixWindows.getFixWindows(this), ToggleDoor.getToggleDoor(), SelectDogPhase.getSelectDogPhase()};

  }

  public static RemotePhase getRemotePhase(){
    if(remotePhase==null){
      remotePhase=new RemotePhase();
    }
    return remotePhase;
  }
}

final class FixWindows extends Phase{
  private static FixWindows windows;
  private RemotePhase remotePhase;

  private FixWindows(){

    //execution keeps coming here as FixWindows object is never constructed
    //remotePhase=RemotePhase.getRemotePhase(); //shoud be deleted

  }

  public static FixWindows getFixWindows(remotePhase){
    if(windows==null){
      windows=new FixWindows();
      windows.setRemotePahse(remotePhase);
    }
    return windows;
  }
}
```