# How to write script in gradle that execute particular methods?

Tags: gradle, junit

I am writing a gradle script that runs all tests before making a build.

```
test {
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching "*TestAll*"
        includeTestsMatching "*ExtensionValidatorTest*"
        ........
    }
}
```

I have three tests of different versions(v1,v2,v3).

**TestAll.java**

```
package .....v1;//v2 for version 2 and v3 for version 3

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
      A.class,
      B.class,
      ......
})
public class TestAll {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {//connection to database
         ........
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown()  {//close database connection 
         ........
    }
}
```

When I run `gradle test` connection to database is broken after execution of a particular TestAll. I do not want to change the TestAll files of any version as they can be run and tested independently. How can I make gradle run only setUp once(of any version)which establishes connection, then run all the TestAll method in v1,v2 and v3 and finally teardown(of any version) which terminates database connection.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle won't help you with this. There are following methods in [Gradle DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:beforeSuite(groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
test {
   beforeSuite{...} 

   afterSuite{...}
}
```

However, they execute outside of the test runtime scope and intended for logging. You only can achieve this using a testing framework.

[TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) provides a simple solution - `@BeforeSuite` and `@AfterSuite` annotations, that are actually run once before and after the entire suite.

Unfortunately, JUnit doesn't have a built-in solution for that, since test isolation is its core concept. Nevertheless, you still can make your own. You need to encapsulate database-related API into a singleton class:

```java
public class DbContainer() {
   private static DbContainer container;

   private DbContaner() {}

   public DbContainer getInstance() {
      if (container == null) {
         container = new DbContainer()
      }
      return container;
   }

   public void openConnection() {
      // ...
   }

   public void closeConnection() {
      // ...
   }

   // here is your database API methods
}
```

Then you can share this instance between test methods and classes using `@ClassRule` annotation:

```java
   @ClassRule
   public static DbContainer db = DbContainer.getInstance(); 

   @Test
   public void someTest() {
      db.query(...)
   }
```

*Note:* provided solution is not thread-safe and doesn't suit the parallel execution. Some [additional effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106260/thread-safe-singleton-class) is required to achieve it.