# NullType vs Void for method argument that is always null

Tags: java, null

I've got some generic processors that get invoked by a framework. Argument is the payload that I process.

```
interface Processor<T, U> {
    U process(T t);
}
```

There are situations in which payload makes no sense and does not exist (only response is calculated and returned). In that case the framework passes `null` as argument. I decided to use [`javax.lang.model.type.NullType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/NullType.html) for that purpose:

```
new Processor<NullType, String>() {
  public String process(NullType unused) {
    ...
    return result;
  }
}
```

Am I misusing the intention of `NullType` here? Is [`java.lang.Void`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) or something else more appropriate?

Comment: *" This is the type of the expression null"* ... so it represents that you want it to represent ... where is the confusion, now?

Comment: @Tom well, potentially that two instances of `NullType` aren't actually equal (as it is an interface) - so they represent `null`, but `Objects.equals(aNullType, bNullType) == false`, whereas `Objects.equals(null, null) == true`.

Comment: When working with the android sdk, `Void` is the commonly used type in these cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer `Void` in these situations, which makes passing a `null` the only valid parameter.

`NullType` on the other hand can be instantiated.

---

As a curiosity, [it is possible to instantiate an object of type `Void`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060078/is-void-really-uninstantiable).

Comment: I agree - here's why: NullType is meant to represent a type. In the same way that ArrayType (in the same package) is not an array, NullType is not null. It's normal to use Void in similar cases, like Callable<Void> or Future<Void>

Comment: I've used `Void` also in similar situations so far, but I always had a feeling that it's meant to deal with return types.